# What 3d simulation software does deepmind use?

Tags: deep-learning

I am looking for the name of simulation software used by Deepmind in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn4nRCC9TwQ)? and what alternative softwares are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's called [OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/). Generally it is is 
a toolkit for developing and comparing reinforcement learning algorithms.

It looks that in the video they' re using `Humanoid model` from [MuJoCo](https://gym.openai.com/envs/#mujoco) which is part of `OpenAI Gym` and [here](http://www.mujoco.org/) you have their offical website.

Regarding to other similar toolkits there is also [DeepMind Lab](https://deepmind.com/blog/open-sourcing-deepmind-lab/)